# Prestashop Custom Module, how to update my sql value?

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I wish to update my sql value for my custom module, but since this value is in a separated sql table, I stuck ...

The first value, MY_TOPBAR, is updated correctly since she is updated in the ps_configuration table, but my second value, MY_HTML_DATA, isn't updated correctly in my table ps_mymodule.

Here is my php code :

```
public function getContent()
    {
        // If we try to update the settings
        $output = '';

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'.$this->name))
        {   
            Configuration::updateValue('MY_TOPBAR', Tools::getValue('MY_TOPBAR', ''));
            Configuration::updateValue('MY_HTML_DATA', Tools::getValue('MY_HTML_DATA', ''));
            Tools::redirectAdmin($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules').'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&conf=4&module_name='.$this->name);
        }
        return $output.$this->displayForm();
    }
```

How I can update correctly my MY_HTML_DATA value ?

Thanks

#

I finally used the method provided by @yenshirak and here it's the final code who permit to update my custom table, without loose of any html data =>

```
public function getContent()
    {
        // If we try to update the settings
        $output = '';

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'.$this->name))
        {   
            Configuration::updateValue('MY_TOPBAR', Tools::getValue('MY_TOPBAR', ''));
        $MY_HTML_DATA = pSQL( Tools::getValue('MY_HTML_DATA', ''), true );
        $sql='UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'mymodule` SET `data` = "'.$MY_HTML_DATA.'" WHERE `option` =\'MY_HTML_DATA\';';
        if(Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql))
            Tools::redirectAdmin($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules').'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&conf=4&module_name='.$this->name);
        }
        return $output.$this->displayForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Db` class to update your custom table:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'mymodule SET your_column_name = "' . pSQL(Tools::getValue('MY_HTML_DATA', '')) . '" WHERE id = your_id';
Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
```

Documentation: [DB class best practices](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/DB+class+best+practices)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's don't work :(
$sql = 'UPDATE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'mymodule` SET data = "' . Tools::getValue('MY_HTML_DATA', '') . '" WHERE option = \'MY_HTML_DATA\';';
Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

Comment: Ok, after some tweaks with the comma that's work like that =>
         $sql='UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'mymodule` SET `data` = "' . Tools::getValue('MY_HTML_DATA', '') . '" WHERE `option` =\'MY_HTML_DATA\';';
         if(Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql))

Comment: But, I don't understand why that's work for small "data" but when I want to save a full table in html for exemple, that's don't work :x

Comment: @WolwxAliasXavierRedondo I edited my answer. You should escape the string with the `pSQL` function.

Comment: Thanks, I digged in that way, with the class pSQL, and after checked many custom modules I found the way to avoid the loose of html data :)

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```php
$query = "UPDATE "._DB_PREFIX_."attribute SET color= '".$imagename."' WHERE id_attribute_group = '".$option_id."'";
Db::getInstance()->Execute($query);
```